# Aligning the x button and the follow unfollow button.

Tags: javascript, php, css, button, html-table

The follow button is aligned right, but I want the x to appear to the right instead of the left of the follow unfollow button. I am using float right for the button, and also float right for the X, but the button floats to the right of the X. How can I reverse these, while maintaining the functionality that when I click on the X the entire row disappears?

I want the X to appear on the right of the button, but if I do this, the functionality will no longer hide the entire row after pressing the X:

[image]

```
<?php
$users = show_users_userspage();
$following = following($_SESSION['user_id']);
if (count($users)){
?>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' width='320'>
<?php

        foreach ($users as $key => $value){
            echo "<tr valign='bottom'>\n";
             "<td>"."<div class='alert alert-success'>".$key ."</td>\n";
            echo "<td><img src='/social_learning/images/thebombthumb.gif'>     ".$value;

            if (in_array($key,$following)){
                echo "<small><a style='margin:10px 20px 0px 5px;float:right;'     class='btn btn-danger btn-mini' href='/social_learning/php/action.php?    id=$key&do=unfollow'>unfollow</a></small><a class='close' style='margin:10px 0px 0px 5px;' data-    dismiss='alert'>×</a></div>";
            }else{
                echo " <small><a style='margin:10px 20px 0px     5px;float:right;' class='btn btn-warning btn-mini' href='/social_learning/php/action.php?     id=$key&do=follow'>follow</a></small><a class='close'style='margin:10px 0px 0px 5px;' data-    dismiss='alert'>×</a></div>";
            }

            echo "</td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float: right works backwards. Just reverse the two (button/x) so that the X is displayed first then the button second.

Comment: WOW such a simple solution. thank you very much. dont know why i didnt see that. especially after spending hours on it.